# Joining 4 tables related

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join these 4 tables:

customers:

- id_customer;
- name;
- surname

employers:

- id_employer;
- id_customer;

products_to_employer

- id_product;
- id_employer;

products

- id_product;
- name_product;
- code;
- price;

Where i basically try to get all products of a customer. Basically each product is related whit a id_employer, but each employer is related whit a customer, so what i want is to bring all the products that is not related whit the employer but whit his "parent" the customer.

The result I want to get is:

Result:

Example: variable $id_customer: 4

products result:

- id_customer (id nr 4)
- name_product;
- name_product;
- code;
- price;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the requirement:

> Where i basically try to get all products of a customer

So it is just a matter of applying some joins and a `where` clause for the filter on `id_customer`

```
select p.* from products p
join products_to_employer pe on p.id_product = pe.id_product
join employers e on pe.id_employer = e.id_employer
join customers c on e.id_customer = c.id_customer
where c.id_customer = 4
```

NOTE: There shouldn't be any need of adding the `id_customer` to the results as you are already filtering by it.

Comment: thanks $Mosty Mostacho but it appears a situation, the query worked fine, but since the employer bot many of the same products in my while loop is bringing reptid product, i liked to bring only one time, is is possible in a sql query?

Comment: Hello, i forget one detail is ot possible to bring the numbers of the employers id @MostyMostacho?

Comment: Yes, i already tryed it and it works, but the problem is the distinct stops taking effect, here is my code @Mosty Mostacho: select distinct p.*, e.id_employer  from products p
join products_to_employers pe on p.id_product = pe.id_product
join employers e on pe.id_employer = e.id_employer
join customers c on e.id_customer = c.id_customer
where c.id_customer = '$id_customer' 
Is bringing duplicated values

Comment: basically @Mosty Mostacho i need the employer beucase in my while loope i need to count how many products that each customer haves. :-)

Comment: Im sorry, i should in the beginning be more explicit, i need th id_employer to count the number of products that each customer got to have, ill attach in this post the image os printscreenshot of the result i want to get, basically i need in the "Nr. products" field appear the number of product bought, than in the field "Total" that appears "Total Number" is the total sum of these products. Sorry for this confusion @Mosty Mostacho

Comment: I won't be able to take a look at this soon. I'd recommend you to formulate a new question and you'll get the answer in a matter of minutes :) If you don't, just send me the link and I'll take a look at it later today

Comment: Sure, can you send me your contact email?

Comment: Just paste the link of the question here if it doesn't get answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id_customer, c.name, p.name_product, p.code, p.price
from products p
    inner join products_to_employer pte on (pte.id_product = p.id_product)
    inner join employers e on (e.id_employer = pte.id_employer)
    inner join customers c on (c.id_customer = e.id_customer)
where c.id_customer = 4
```